# How to Embed Excel Formula in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to embed excel formula in SSRS Report so that user who downloaded the report into excel could use these formulas directly? For example, we have the following SSRS report:

[image]

We want to embed a formula in the Total Sales cell in SSRS report, so that if user downloaded the report into excel and changed the sales in Location B from 20 to 25, then total would automatically change from 30 to 35. Like the following one:
[image]

Any Suggestions would be helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: I fairly sure that this is not possible.

Comment: Got it, thanks Rono~